# Building a log parser analyzer

Tags: python

I am a final year student and my project is to build a log parser analyzer.
I am planning to make use of python to write a script which will parse any log file across platforms(windows,Linux..etc).
I would really appreciate it if any one could explain me the workflow, like where to start from and how to go about writing a log parser.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to start:

```
my assumption is: the logfiles will be flat files

questions that you probably need to answer before getting into the code:
  will all the logfiles have the same layout or may each have a separate configuration?                    
  what constitutes a record?
  what constitutes a field?
  what are their delimiters?
  how will the parse results be presented?  and how often?
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my query. Yes it would be a flat file and the parse results will be analysed for any kind of intrusion and if there is an intrusion it will be communicated to the administrator through the email. am planning the parse the files every five minutes.